# Microsoft Orleans - How to activate X reminder grains in different silos?

Tags: azure, orleans

Is there a way in Orleans to make sure X reminder grains of same type are hosted on different silos?

Motivation:
I want to use Orleans in an Azure cloud service that runs background processing and should be highly resilient to failures and to silos downtime due to in-place upgrade. In my scenario there is a need for a grain that is always active doing it's job using timers, and if it’s hosting silo goes down then it should be activated again on another silo in few seconds. During an Azure cloud service upgrade, the instances are divided into 5 groups, one group is upgraded at a time, which means during an upgrade I always have 20% of my instances shut down, which makes it challenging to have an always active grain. I consulted with Sergey Bykov and we came up with several ideas, one of them was introducing “keep alive” grains that their purpose is to ping the “always active” grain to make sure it’s active. In order to make that work during upgrades, I need to make sure there is always at least one “keep alive” grain that its hosting silo isn’t in the same upgrade group as the silo that hosts the “always active” grain, so that “keep alive” grain will be able to make the “always active” grain be re-activated on another silo that isn’t shutdown at that moment.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of an actor based system like Orleans if you need to do that. Why can't you run the timer outside of orleans?

Comment: also what we usually did was to just have a single upgrade domain for orleans, which mitigates the swapping grains (with a bit of downtime of course)

Comment: I have alternative designs which fit better to an actor based system, but they have their own complexities. Most of the scenarios my cloud service should support fit very well with virtual actors abstraction, there is only this one scenario that doesn't fit actors naturally, so I'm exploring options. Regarding a single upgrade domain, under no circumstances will I allow downtime for my service due to deployments/upgrades. My SLA leaves room only for real problems that cause downtime, not well known disruptions I can prepare myself for with the proper design.

Comment: By inspecting some of Orleans tests I see that a placement strategy called "ActivationCountBasedPlacement" may be what I need. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I recently was reading the [Orleans Timers and Reminders documentation](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Advanced-Concepts/Timers-and-Reminders) which contained the following nugget which may be relevant.  Highlighting is my own.

## Reminders

### Description

Reminders are similar to timers with a few important differences:

- Reminders are persistent and will continue to trigger in all situations (including partial or full cluster restarts) unless explicitly cancelled.
- Reminders are associated with a grain, not any specific activation.
- If a grain has no activation associated with it and a reminder ticks, **one will be created. e.g.: If an activation becomes idle and is deactivated, a reminder associated with the same grain will reactivate the grain when it ticks next.**
- Reminders are delivered by message and are subject to the same interleaving semantics as all other grain methods.
- Reminders should **not** be used for high-frequency timers– their period should be measured in *minutes, hours, or days*.

## Further Comments

It is possible that this isn't a solution in your case because of the final note about high-frequency.  If you have a single point of failure that can't go down, it might be relevant to consider alternative solutions. :-/

The particular case that I am looking at using this for is precisely for a 5 minute polling interval.  I need to call a web service, gather some data and then process it.

My only other thought is to make my polling-based implementation super lightweight so that it can be quickly brought up to speed as the underlying infrastructure is changed.

It appears that there is a decent bit of [documentation here](http://richorama.github.io/blog/2015/01/02/grain-placement-in-orleans/) regarding activation placement strategies.